# Why black sand beaches have black sand?

Tags: beaches

[image]

Why black sand beaches have black sand?

Comment: Why the question down votes? There is a reason why sand is coloured differently...although admittedly it’s easy to find through an internet search rather than posting a question here

Comment: @Traveller Because this question is not about travelling at all. It's about geology. Answering such questions we can end up with questions "why don't penguins live in Iceland" or "why is the capital of whatever-country called so"

Comment: @Neusser Ok, thanks, I get that. Although I think the OP may  have English as a second language (or third etc) and therefore might have taken your comment literally, leading to an equally unacceptable follow-up question. In my experience, non native speakers don’t easily recognise veiled sarcasm :-)

Comment: @Traveller Okay, I deleted it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: You may be interested in [EarthScience.SE], where such questions may be on-topic if a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black sand is most common on the coasts of volcanic islands (Hawai’i, the Canary Islands, the Aleutians, etc.). Black sand beaches are black because they are composed of volcanic minerals and lava fragments, which are dark-coloured. http://www.sandatlas.org/colors-in-sand/